# Bipolar power from unipolar supply, but accounting for DC offset

Tags: power, synthesizer

I've been researching this one during the past week. I've found lots of examples of split rails, but nothing which addresses my concerns.

I'm creating a new circuit board for an existing cv/expression pedal for a synthesizer. This is basically a pot that lets you output a voltage between two values. The values I need to support are 0 to 5v, 0 to 10v, and -5v to +5v. The current requirement is extremely low (in the 10s of ma).

[image: Behringer FCV100 pedal]

Because I'm modifying this existing pedal, and because I would like to provide this replacement board to other people to use, I'd like to use the existing 12v DC power supply that the pedal is typically used with.

**The twist:** I don't think a virtual ground can work because the synthesizers already have a ground reference (sleeve on the 1/4" jack) that this will need to work with (the reference is based on standard AC power). If I use a split rail design with a virtual ground at something like 6v (using op-amps, resistors, or that cool TI chip), **won't I have a 6v DC offset that needs to be subtracted out somehow before the signal leaves the pedal?** If so, how would I go about offsetting that?

I know there is a way to do this, because I've seen another pedal which does exactly this with a standard DC unipolar power supply. The only part of this that is giving me problems is figuring out the -5v to +5v part.

I'm self-taught in electronics, and so there are lots of things here that I'm ignorant of, but I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thanks.

Pete

**Update:** This is how I'll switch between the three voltages. The original pedal had a slide switch on the opposite side of the photo. I'm going to replace it with a small 3-way slider.

[image: Range selection block]

Comment: Charge pump inverter with a couple of TO-92 or SOT-23 regulators.

Comment: @Pete, Are you planning on a switch to change between the three voltage ranges?  Can you float the existing 12V DC supply or is it used in some other part of the circuit?  If not then a little inverter as suggested by Ignacio would be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks George. Yes, I'm planning a three-way switch along with trim pots to allow fine tuning of the voltage range. I completely control what happens with the 12v power supply because I'm completely replacing the circuit board in the pedal. Between the 12v input and the three outputs, I own everything in the middle. I just need to make sure the output works with the external equipment.

Comment: George, I've updated the question with the range selection bit of the schematic.

Comment: Regulators would remove the need for manual adjustment (unless you need sub-20mV precision).

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. I may go that route, but there's some benefit to being able to fine tune the range, especially when working with older synthesizers. My Korg Mono/Poly (built in 1981) is what inspired me to do this project. In any case, I'll pick a direction after I build and test the prototype.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. Do you think the charge pump inverter is a better solution than ioplex's floating power supply idea below? I'm reading up on charge pump inverters now to better understand benefits/downsides.

Comment: Just a quick note that I've been slammed with travel and whatnot, so haven't tried the two suggestions here yet. When I do, I'll post the results. Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a virtual ground circuit with the virtual ground connected to the sleeve of the synth CV input. But it will only work if the pedal power supply is floating. If it's not floating, it would indeed be a short and something would probably burst into flames. But a wall wart supply is almost certainly either a transformer or switching supply that in either case are probably floating. So you can assign ground to be whatever you want (in this case the synth ground). But you need to test to make sure by creating the virtual ground circuit, put a 1M resistor between the sleeve and virtual ground and then put a meter across the resistor to see if there is a voltage across it. If there is, the supply is not floating. There might be a small voltage indicating a small current (1V across 1M would be 1uA) which is fine. But hopefully the voltage will be really small like 50 mV or so. If that is the case, you can connect the virtual ground and sleeve of the CV in. But you might want to use a small resistor like 100R just in case someone plugs in a non-floating supply so that it doesn't burst into flames immediately. Or maybe use a 10 mA fuse.

Note that I very much doubt the CV uses 10's of mA. 10 mA is enough current to light an LED pretty bright. The currents involved are probably 10 uA and not 10 mA.

Note that you will need to check the pedal CV for noise (while connected to the synth) using an oscilloscope or (PC audio interface if you don't have a scope). Whenever you connect two devices with different supplies, there is great potential for noise. But using the synth ground as the ground for the expression pedal might be just the fix for that sort of noise problem.

Comment: Thanks. I do have a scope, so I can check noise. I had no idea that those power supplies were often floating. I assume that the ones with three prong connections are not, but I'd need to test. I assume if non-floating, the ground pin on the AC side plug would have continuity with ground on the DC connector?

Comment: The 3rd prong on a 3 prong plug is supposed to be just for grounding metal parts like the chassis of an appliance. The neutral prog is "ground" and may or may not have continuity with the DC connector. If it does, then yeah, it's definitely not floating. But even if it doesn't it may still not be floating. Switching supplies are getting very sophisticated nowadays. I think the best way to check would be to actually wire up a simple votage divider and see if a resistor between it and the synth ground generates a current. But again, test with a big resistor between the grounds first.

Comment: Actually if you think about it, if the supply plug is 2 prong, then it pretty much has to be floating because someone could plug it in either way. So if one prong was connected to the DC ground, it could connect the DC ground to the wall outlet load. Even if it were 3 prong, it would have to be floating because wall outlets are frequently wired incorrectly. So the supply pretty much has to be floating.